# how to determine the no of occurrences of a letter in a string using python without built in functions or counters

Tags: python, python-3.x

i do have a rough idea to use ord and id function to obtain values of the letters in a string but no idea how to increment for every other similar occurrence of the same value.This is my Interview personal preparation. Please give me idea and suggestion no codes.

Comment: no of all occurrences of the letters in a string

Comment: create a dictionary while looping through a string?

Comment: Pretend you're a computer and do it on paper in pseudocode. Then translate it into Python and move the algorithm into the interpreter and test it out.

Comment: That said, if you need help with a basic question like this, isn't that kind of a sign that you [might not be ready for that sort of job](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)?

Comment: I don't really understand the restrictions here. No functions? No counters? Throw that `dict` idea away because the values are just integers you're incrementing, right? Isn't that a counter? Also, better not use the `in` keyword since that calls `__contains__` (a function).

Comment: really no `Counter`?

Comment: Also, you'll have to clarify what you mean by "counter," because it's kind of hard to determine how many times something appears without counting in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Without using built in functions or counters, I would think outside the box. Just put a comment that instructs the user what to do physically at their desk. This uses just enough Python to get the job done without using any of the built in functions.

```
"""
Using a pencil, write down the word, then starting at the first letter:
Write down the letter and put a dash or tick or something next to it
Look for that letter in the word, and add additional marks next to the letter to keep track of the count.
When you've reached the end of the word, go to the next letter and repeat the process 
Skip any letters that you have already counted(Otherwise instead of the count of each letter's occurrences, you'll get the factorial of the count!)
"""
```

Comment: Might as well do `"""1. Count how many times each letter appears."""`. I'd be surprised if this was intended as a trick question, but if it was, it shouldn't be on SO.

Answer (score -1):

User a counter variable, something like this should get you started:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> meaty = 'asjhdkajhskjfhalksjhdflaksjdkhaskjd'
>>> for i in meaty:
...   if i == 'a':
...     count+=1
...
>>> print count
5
```

if you are tracking multiple occurrences of multiple letters, user the letter as a dictionary key that stores a counter integer:

```
>>> count = {}
>>> for i in meaty:
...   key = i
...   if key in count:
...     count[key]+=1
...   else:
...     count[key]=1
...
>>> count
{'a': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 2, 'h': 5, 'k': 6, 'j': 6, 'l': 2, 's': 5}
```

Edit: Meh, no counter, no built in functions, no coding examples on Stack Overflow? Not sure how to count without counting and isn't python essentially a collection of built in functions? Isn't Stack Overflow for actual coding help?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus - To be fair, I don't see how one could determine the quantity of some arbitrary object without some kind of counting going on in some way, whether with `num+=1`, `collections.Counter`, or `len()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I completely agree, that's why I haven't posted an answer ;) T'was just to be on the same page as the OP.